# Which vmlinuz and initrd.img should I use for 'headless' CentOS installation?

Tags: centos, installation, grub, vmlinuz

I am pondering reinstalling a CentOS Linux server remotely, by installing CentOS' installer into /boot (GRUB) as per this tutorial:
[ganesh.me: Install Linux Servers Remotely](http://www.ganesh.me/29-install-linux-servers-remotely.html)

I notice that there are two different versions of vmlinuz and initrd.img in the CentOS 6 distribution:

- at
  [centos/6.5/os/x86_64/isolinux/](http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/isolinux/)
- at
  [centos/6.5/os/x86_64/images/pxeboot/](http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/images/pxeboot/)

What is each one for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the /isolinux/ ones are for booting a live CD using [ISOLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/ISOLINUX), whereas the pxeboot ones are for booting CentOS from a [PXE](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/PXE_boot_server) server. PXE booting is when you obtain the kernel and initrd from another server using a TFTP client built into the network interface. Typically you'll see something like "Network Boot" in the boot list in your BIOS.

Comment: So, that means that neither of the file sets is _intended_ for my usage scenario? Maybe some of the files (boot.iso, efiboot.img, efidisk.img, install.img) at [centos/6.5/os/x86_64/images/](http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/images/) are fore me?

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, if you're just trying to find the files for the installer, and have a good internet connection on the server, then the PXE files should work for the installation. However, I have never performed this process before, so I can't say for certain.

Answer (score -2):

"Download the PXE boot initrd.img and vmlinuz files to your /boot."